# Users can sign-up on our portal using linkedin but we are unable to access their linkedin ID. How do track the linkedin ID with email address?

Tags: linkedin-api

We are a platform that facilitates companies to hire analytics talent on demand. We only allow users to login to our platform with their Linkedin IDs so that we can validate their profile details and score them. Currently, the Linkedin API doesnot give us even the Linkedin-id of the user to help us manually check the profile. How can we correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Ask for the r_liteprofile and r_emailaddress scopes as part of the OAuth flow. Then make  GET calls to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me and [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle%7E)))
to gather this information. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) for more details.

However, please read LinkedIn's API Terms of Use to ensure your application is an acceptable use case. Also, the profile data you can receive is quite limits, so it may not give you the fields you want.

Comment: Thanks Adam I will ask my development team to look into this. But what about  the previous users whose email IDs I have and no Linkedin IDs? is there a way to get their Linkedin IDs as well?

Comment: Thanks Adam I will ask my development team to look into this. But what about the previous users whose email IDs I have and no Linkedin IDs? is there a way to get their Linkedin IDs as well? #linkedin

Comment: If you have a bunch of email addresses, and want to pull their LinkedIn profile, then this is not a supported use case. But now we are getting far beyond the technical scope of Stack, so let's end this thread to keep us on topic. Thanks.